# "Насаженки". Етимолоґія. Синоніми

Tags: етимологія, синоніми, невідоме-слово

Знову ж таки, "Дівчина з ведмедиком" Домонтовича.

> Я **«насаженки»**. Зина — лівим боком. Ми пливемо повільно й розмірено.

Тобто, це спосіб плисти.

Тільки що це за спосіб?

Ґуґл для ["насаженки"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&oq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i59j69i61l2j69i59.3072j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) показує лише один результат, що це саме і є "Дівчина з ведмедиком", тож навіть не знаю, звідки почати пошуки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Грінченко](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=49157)

> **Сажень**, *-жна*, м.
>
> 4. **плавати сажнями.** Плавать, вытягивая руки.

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах.](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) — [Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 15.](http://sum.in.ua/s/sazhenj)

> 5. *тільки множина*, *спорт*. Спосіб плавання на грудях, під час якого плавець по черзі викидає над водою то одну, то другу випростану руку. *Сам Ігнат був ще молодий козак.., скакати через куполове огнище або перемахати сажнями Дніпро — ото були його забавки* (Пантелеймон Куліш, Вибр., 1969, 271); Пливти сажнями.

[Етимологічний словник української мови](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) — частина 5, сторінки 163—164

> **са́жень** (міра довжини)
>
> *посаже́нний*
>   *сага́* — *Верхратський І.* Говір батюків. Львів, 1912
>   *са́жен* — [? Куз] *Кузнецов П. С.*  Очерки по морфологии праславянского языка. Москва, 1961
>   *са́жінь* — *Дзендзелівський Й. О.* Словник специфічної лексики говірок Нижнього Подністровʼя. — Лексикографічний бюлетень (Інституту мовознавства АН УРСР), випуск 6, Київ, 1958
>   *ся́жень*, *саже́нний, сажне́вий, сажньови́й, [соже́нний] «саженний»* — *Желехівський Є. Недільський С.* Малорусько-німецький словар. Т. 2. Львів, 1886
>
> російська *са́жень*, білоруська *са́жань*, давньоруська сяжень, польська sążeń, чеська sáh, старе sažeň, словацька siaha, верхньолужицька sažeň. нижньолужицька sežań, болгарська і македонська *са́жен*, сербохорватська *се̏жањ*, словенська séženj
>
> прасловʼянська *sęgъ, *sęženь, повʼязане з sęgati «простягати руку»;
>
> первісно означало довжину, вимірювану розставленими руками;
>
> зіставлення з литовською síeksnis «сажень» (Mikkola IF 8, 302) необґрунтоване
>
> Черных 2 135; Фасмер 3 545; Булаховський Вибр. пр 3 428; Brückner 483; Machek ESJČ 535
>
> Дивіть ще **сяга́ти**